# sqlite random file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have an application that frequently accesses a sqlite database.  It works great most of the time but occasionally in one of my database functions fails and returns:

> file is encrypted or is not a database

I don't have any encryption enabled but I can't pinpoint how this is happening.  It's not consistently reproducible and from the crash logs, it happens on the main thread.

Thanks in advance.

```
@synchronized(self) {
    sqlite3 *database = mydb;
    int result = 0;

    static sqlite3_stmt *stmt = nil;
    if (stmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "select sum(not isAvailable) from table1 e inner join table2 f on e.key=f.pk where f.pk=? AND e.isDeleting=0;";
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }

    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, obj.primaryKey);

    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        int val = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
        result = val;
    } else {
        [NSException raise:@"SQL Fail" format:@"SQL Failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database)];
    }
    // Reset the statement for future reuse.
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Version mismatch perhaps?

Comment: i asked google and the most popular answer is version mismatch but i don't understand how this can happen only sometimes for this query...updated post with sample code

Comment: @CodaFi -- I'm pretty sure that the SQLite file version hasn't changed in an incompatible fashion in a number of years.  "Version mismatch" is the usual explanation offered, but it doesn't explain anything.

Comment: are you opening/closing the file rapidly? then Id guess it is IO related!

Comment: the only time i call close the file is in applicationWillTerminate:

Comment: Where are you storing this database file?

Comment: the documents directory

Comment: Since you say it recovers if you restart the app, I'm leaning towards some sort of heap corruption scenario.  It's important to read carefully the SQLite spec with regard to how `char*` and `void*` values returned from API calls are managed, in addition to following all the iOS heap management rules.

Comment: Have you made any further attempts at debugging this in the past month?  There is not enough information here for anyone to give you a simple answer.

Comment: how many data store and manage object context do u used? if u use more than please change it to one and execute the same code

Comment: Care to have a look at ["How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File"](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new encrypted SQLite database or to open an existing encrypted SQLite database you have to call the function sqlite3_key or to execute a "pragma key=" command immediately after opening the database before performing any other database operation.
I suspect that you tried to open an existing database, but not encrypted SQLite database and expected to encrypt it by using one of the above methods. This doesn't work but results in the error message you experienced.
To encrypt an existing not encrypted SQLite database you have to use function sqlite3_rekey or "pragma rekey=" command.
To change the encryption key of an existing encrypted SQLite database you have to open the database, then to use sqlite3_key (or "pragma key=") and then to apply sqlite3_rekey (or "pragma rekey=").

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when the DB file somehow becomes garbled.  Exactly why this might occur, though, is a bit of a puzzle.

If you are writing other files in your app, you may have accidentally overwritten the DB file.  And if you were to open the same DB file twice or do two "simultaneous" operations on the DB you *might* be able to create this scenario (but I think that most versions of SQLite are compiled with the code to detect this and error out if there's a conflict).  (Question:  Do you ever get the "database is locked" error instead?)

Comment: i'm also writing to a log file...but the weird thing is after i get this error, the app runs fine on next launch as if nothing happened...i haven't seen database is locked either

Comment: @HotLicks How is "somehow garbled" any less vague (in principle) than a version mismatch?  A garbled database can be caused by something as simple as not committing a transaction, and something as complicated as botching a migration to a new version.

Comment: @CodaFi - A version mismatch (if even possible) wouldn't occur unless a new version of either DB or the SQLite lib is installed, so could never "just happen" with a previously-running-fine app.  And I have to believe that there is a separate error message for version mismatch, vs the encrypted message.

Comment: @VTS12 - If it's fine the next time you run, that suggests that there is a problem with heap management and the SQLite control structures or buffers are getting clobbered, not the DB itself.

Comment: @CodaFi - And the main problem with calling it a "version mismatch" is that that is even less helpful than saying "haven't the foggiest", since it sends you looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: pointless arguing aside...you think it could be related to a memory issue within the app?  i think that's possible, but that wouldn't explain why it only happens in that one database function (we have probably over 75 different database calls but it's only this one that crashes)

Comment: Heap error is probably the best bet.  You often tend to have reference patterns that unreliably reproduce the same error again and again.  I'd look at the operations that were likely performed on the DB in the 2-3 references prior to the failure point.  Look for the use of functions such as `sqlite3_column_blob` which give out heap addresses.  If these are not used in conformance with the rules then strange things can result.  (Just about any blob operation is suspect.)

Comment: Note in particular that if any SQLite heap address is somehow cast to be a iOS-managed pointer type then you're in trouble.

Comment: is there any way I can verify it's some kind of heap error? this seems reasonable but i have no idea how to fix / narrow this down

Comment: i also want to note that i have WAL enabled...not sure if that matters

Comment: You can always try disabling it, just to see if it changes anything.  Often with this sort of thing you just have to play around until you find something that seems related.

Comment: unfortunately due to a few other requirements we need to have wal enabled...so overall...this is caused by a memory management issue? i just don't understand why it only happens in this 1 function

Comment: We don't know that it's caused by a memory management issue, but it seems like the most likely cause.  Sometimes debugging is not simple.

Comment: @VTS12,Hot Licks : I am facing the same issue. I want a solution. What should I do..?

Comment: @anilkukdeja - You debug it.

Comment: @Hot Licks : I have debugged already for few days you know.Then I have upgraded from core sqlite to FMDB. But issue remains the same. Randomly it returns 'nil' result set of select query. What is the solution of it..? Please let me know. I am stuck here very badly.

Comment: @anilkukdeja - More debugging.  Use a hex editor to compare the problem file to a known good SQLite file, to see if there is any resemblance, and to see if the bad file appears to have been overwritten by some other recognizable data.  Make note of what else was going on when the failures occur.  If necessary create some sort of log to track what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

As unhelpful as the "version mismatch" advice often is, I was experiencing the same symptoms and found that the problem was fixed by updating the database from version 2 to 3.  Maybe one of the reasons this problem occurs is that the file extension for the database doesn't necessarily correctly reflect the real version number.

I could be mistaken, but when I created my first SQLite database using SQLite Administrator version 0.8.3.2 and accepted the default "Save as type" of SQLite3 DB, the file it created was apparently a version 2 DB despite having a .s3db name.  Under the Databases menu, the item "Migrate to SQLite3" was enabled but I figured this was a mistake in the GUI.  However, after employing that feature, my problem disappeared.

Subsequent use of the Database|New option in SQLite Administrator creates a DB of the version I choose, and the file-extension matches the convention for that version.  The erroneous behavior of SQL Administrator only occurred the first time I used the Database|New option.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today.

It turned out to be that, I was creating a column called Time in my database. Changed that to TimeStamp and it worked. I thought that somehow my file had been corrupt so i was looking at the sql code to generate the table (to redo it on a new file) when i noticed "Time" highlighted in blue indicating it was a reserved word.